# Braille text in blender

Tags: text-object, 3d-printing

I'd like to use blender to add some text in braille to some blender 3D modela in order to print them via 3D printers.
Is it possible in an easy way? How?

Answer (score 8):

I know nothing about braille but this should be as simple as grabbing a suitable font and extruding it. I tried [braille normal](http://www.fontspace.com/philing/braille-normal) from fontspace. Once in Blender, add a *Text* object, edit it as needed and then navigate to the `.ttf` font file under *Font*, the *Regular* input should be enough.

[image]

One you are satisfied, you can edit the *Extrude* slider for the depth or convert it to an object and play with it some more (booleans etc).

Comment: Note that braille normally uses a lot of contractions and while people will probably be able to read the plain text in a braille font they may find it more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an automated way to use Braille in Blender.

iKlsR approach can be very problematic if the layout of the dots in the font does not match the dimensional standards of Braille:  https://www.ukaaf.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Braille-Standard-Dimensions.pdf

I made the Blend file according to this standard (dimensions and proportions) and am currently using it for 3D printing:
https://stikey.net/download/braille/BRAILLE_3D_print_v3.blend

Way of use:

I previously created the Inscape SVG file following the standards (with PharmaBraille Unicode font):
https://stikey.net/download/braille/braille_font_example.svg

There I type the desired text and based on the obtained Braille symbols, in Blender I manually delete unnecessary points.

If anyone notices a possible improvement, please post it here.

PharmaBrailleUnicode-Grid.otf font download:
https://www.pharmabraille.com/pharmaceutical-braille/free-braille-font/

You can find a printout of symbols/letters for other languages here:
https://www.perkins.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/world-braille-usage-third-edition.pdf

3d printing of Braille can be very problematic for practical use.
Consult professionals before using printed models for public purposes.

[image: braille blender file]